# Overlay font awesome icons with less/css

Tags: html, css, less, font-awesome

I want to create a custom icon using font awesome overlays, which I can easily using the following html

```
<span style="width: 18px; height: 18px; line-height: 18px;" class="fa-stack">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x" style="color: rgb(20, 77, 99); font-size: 18px;"></i>
    <i style="font-size: 12px;" class="fa fa-question fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

I can simplify it a bit my removing the inline CSS, but what I would like is to be able to wrap the whole think in a css class for ease of reuse, so that I can just do something like

```
<i class="fa fa-my-icon"></i>
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to create a CSS rule that generates the DOM elements needed.  Is this possible, and if so any pointers as to how it can be done?  I'm not too familiar with less, but a solution based on that would be fine too.

I know how to do it using javascript, but I want to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out with less.  In case anyone else is trying to do this:

```
@import "font-awesome/less/variables.less";

@icon-size: 18px;

.icon-mixin() {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

.my-icon {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: @icon-size;
    height: @icon-size;
    line-height: @icon-size;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: blue;

    &:before {
        content: @fa-var-circle;
        font-size: 18px;
        .icon-mixin;
    }
    &:after {
        content: @fa-var-question;
        vertical-align: middle;
        color: @fa-inverse;
        .icon-mixin;
    }
}
```